# Footer at the bottom of DIV not bottom of page. Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

I want my footer to be at the bottom of the page. Not at the bottom of the content in the DIV that its in. But I also want the footer to dynamically resize when the side bar on the page is opened and closed.

I've spend TOO long trying all options I can find on google with no luck. The best I've managed is to have the footer across the whole page including overlapping the sidebar which is not what i'm after.

Side note:

I also want main content to not scroll under the footer and stop just above. I.e the scroll bar for this div to stop just above the footer if this is easily achievable?

Have a look at Facebook messenger web for a perfect example. The left sidebar and centre content is what I'm looking for.

Can anyone assist?

Example jsfille here:

https://jsfiddle.net/pwdt95u8/1/

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c551403873.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js"
            integrity="sha256-yr4fRk/GU1ehYJPAs8P4JlTgu0Hdsp4ZKrx8bDEDC3I=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="../static/css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

<div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar-heading">Start Bootstrap</div>
        <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Dashboard</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Shortcuts</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Overview</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Events</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Profile</a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Status</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light border-bottom">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</button>

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                           data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Dropdown
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="container-fluid h-100">
            <h1 class="mt-4">Simple Sidebar</h1>
            <div class="row text-left w-50">
            TEST


              <footer id="sticky-footer" class="float-bottom card-footer py-4 bg-dark text-white-50">
                <div class="container text-center">
                  <small>Copyright &copy; Your Website</small>
                </div>
              </footer>


        </div>
    </div>  <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

</div>
<!-- Footer -->



<!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
<script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: dont wrap the footer inside a div. exclude it from the div and leave it as its own object with only body as parent. then give it a `position: sticky` with `bottom: 0;`

Comment: Probably a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is best solved with CSS Grids. In fact there doesn't need to be too many changes. I have moved the footer to be the last child of the body element and added a few properties to the body style rule. (I've also made a few edits such as switching JQuery for Vanilla JS)

I added the *toggle text* button so you can easily toggle text within the main content area.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Richardinho/uw5hLx7p/) is a JFiddle of same code.

```js
document.getElementById('menu-toggle').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('wrapper').classList.toggle('toggled');
});


document.getElementById('text-toggle').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('lorem-ipsum').classList.toggle('hide-text');
});
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;

  /*  last row is footer and takes whatever is its natural height.
   *  first row is rest of content and stretches to fill available space
   */ 

  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#wrapper {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#sticky-footer {
  flex-shrink: none;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  margin-left: -15rem;
  transition: margin 0.25s ease-out;
}

#sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-heading {
  padding: 0.875rem 1.25rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

#sidebar-wrapper .list-group {
  width: 15rem;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  min-width: 100vw;
}

.hide-text {
  display: none;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  margin-left: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  #page-content-wrapper {
    min-width: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    margin-left: -15rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">

      <div class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <div class="sidebar-heading">Start Bootstrap</div>
        <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Dashboard</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Shortcuts</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Overview</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Events</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Profile</a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Status</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="page-content-wrapper">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light border-bottom">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</button>
        </nav>

        <div class="container-fluid">
          <h1 class="mt-4">Simple Sidebar</h1>
          <div class="p1">
            TESTing
            <br/>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="text-toggle">toggle text</button>
            <div id="lorem-ipsum">
            <p>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
            <p>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
            <p>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
            </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <footer id="sticky-footer" class="float-bottom card-footer py-4 bg-dark text-white-50">
      <div class="container text-center">
        <small>Copyright &copy; Your Website</small>
      </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```